# Asp.net core publish apache

Tags: c#, .net, apache, asp.net-core

I am trying to publish my Asp.net core web application on an Apache server. I have purchased a domain on onlydomains.com and published my web app via ftp. The publishing is successful but the website is not working since there are some configuration to be done but i don't know which and i am not able to find any documentation.

This is what my website looks like after publishing:
[image]

Since asp.net core is cross-platform, i am sure it is possible to publish to some hosting provider such as Siteground, Godaddy, Onlydomains etc, right?

Answer (score 1):

Its not a (stfu) PHP. Run your app by `dotnet <patch_to_your_dll_app>` and then use Apache as reverse proxy. I reccomend to read first official docs about [publishing app with Apache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/apache-proxy)

Comment: ok thank you! So i should be able to publish my website on onlydomain or any other type of internet hosting provider?